# Collection Instance Containing Vertex Instancing Shows Original Mesh

Tags: instances, collections

I was trying to streamline instancing in a Blender 4.0 project and found the following difficulty:

While concealing an original mesh in the final render using the 'DupliVerts' vertex instance technique is fine, trying to use the vertex-based instance in a collection instance shows the original mesh in the render.

Have I tried to push Blender too far or have I simply missed something?

QB
[image: Blender View]
Blender View showing source meshes and instances

[image: Render View]
Render showing vertex instance (left) and collection instance of vertex instance (right)

[image]